# problem in itemClick

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, scope

```
if (theData.hasOwnProperty("@id1")) {
    var myObj:Hello = new Hello();
    textArea.visible = false;               
    panel.addChild(myObj);
} else if (theData.hasOwnProperty("@id2")) {
    textArea.visible = false;
    var vijay:MCQ = new MCQ();
    panel.addChild(vijay);
}
```

When i click on the next item, the previous window is still visible. How can i destroy myObj. I am not able to do it through removeChild.

Answer (score 1):

If panel only ever contains one object, you could use the following before adding the new one:

```
panel.removeAllChildren();
```

If there are a known number of "static" children in panel, you could conditionally remove the additional ones:

```
while (panel.numChildren > EXPECTED) {
    panel.removeChildAt(panel.numChildren - 1);
}
```

The best option would be to hold a reference to the object you added so that you can remove it explicitly using removeChild().  If these alternatives won't work, perhaps you could explain your constraints.

Comment: I'd like to point out that removeAllChildren is a Flex only thing, NOT AS3 in general, such as for Flash, so that no one gets confused :)